# Create monthly tabs in excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code in VBA which will use the specific date in the cell 'B1' and create new tabs in excel which will be the date in 'B1' + one month. I am new to VBA, and for this reason do not know how to write a code, I will appreciate your help. To the moment I have the following code, but it creates only one sheet, and for previous month, not for future one, and I do not know how to link it to the cell B1 in the existing tab. In addition, I would like to have a code which will create monthly sheets for next 5 years. Below is what I currently have:

```
Private Sub MonthlyUpdate2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.name = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "MMM-YY")
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code and adjust var `nb_month_to_create` as you want. I suppose that b1 date is in your 1st sheet but you can adjust the name "sheet1"

```
Private Sub MonthlyUpdate2()
    Dim datestart As Date
    datestart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value

    Dim nb_month_to_create As Integer
    nb_month_to_create = 5 * 12 '5 years

  For i = 1 To nb_month_to_create
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = Format(DateAdd("m", i, datestart), "MMM-YY")
    End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code, it works incredibly perfect!

Comment: Great pleasure to help you :)

Comment: @MrMirzayev if this answer helped you resolve your issue, please accept it by clicking the green V on the left ;) thx

Answer (score 2):

Set a var to the date value in B1 before creating the new worksheet so that you can use it in the naming process..

```
Private Sub MonthlyUpdate2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, dt as long
    With ThisWorkbook
        dt = activesheet.range("B1").value2
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.name = Format(DateAdd("m", 1, dt), "MMM-YY")
    End With
End Sub
```

A date is just a number representing the number of days since 31-Dec-1899. For this purpose, a long integer is just as suitable as a date var. Also note -1 became 1 in DateAdd.

There is some confusion as to where the B1 cell actually is so I've used ActiveSheet (the one you can see). This isn't always the best method and a properly defined parent worksheet is preferred.